# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

After i updated some packages (Android Support Design) on my project, an error appeared:

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap

I don't know why i have this. I changed my target android version, but the error is still here.

I'm using the latest version of xamarin, and i'm still in debug, with proguard disable.

Any ideas?

`packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
   <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common" version="1.0.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
   <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime" version="26.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: Can you add which packages did you update?

Comment: @Signo The package is Android Support Design

Comment: @French_FitGirl ok, please also add your `packages.config` to the question, the issue is probably related to some conflicting version of the installed libraries

Comment: @Signo this is my packages.config <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages><package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common" version="1.0.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime" version="26.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid81" />

Comment: @French_FitGirl one of the packages seems to be deprecated, try with my solution. Also how did you add the Android Support Design? Using jar libraries? Because it seems to be available also from [Xamarin here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/)

Comment: @French_FitGirl Having the same issue for days, did you figure out how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The version `26.1.0` of the package `Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime` is [listed as deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime/26.1.0):

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package
>   is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Try by removing this package and adding it again with the [current version 1.0.3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime/1.0.3.1).

Then do a `clean` and `rebuild` of the project.

Comment: i updated the package Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime to the latest version, and do a clean/ rebuild of the project, and i'm still had the error. I also enabled multidex, and keep the android/arch/core/internal.class, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when i migrated

**From**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
```

**To**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

and realized i need to add this extra dependency for **design 27.1.1** to work

```
implementation 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
```

That's all.